# Spring with XML - Return Elements outside of a List

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a system that specification says that the entity XML traveled through the web service controller endpoints must be like this:

```
<SAAF>
    <vehicle>
        <Information>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>  
        </Information>
        <Entry>
            [... entry variables ..]
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            [... entry variables ..]
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            [... entry variables ..]
        </Entry>
    </vehicle>    
</SAAF>
```

But, I only managed to do this:

```
<SAAF>
  <vehicle>
    <information>
      <quantity>3</quantity>
    </information>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            [...entry variables...]
        </entry>
        <entry>
            [...entry variables...]
        </entry>
        <entry>
            [...entry variables...]
        </entry>
    </entries>
  </vehicle>
</SAAF>
```

This is the **VehicleRoot** class:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "vehicle")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "Information", "Entries" })
public class VehicleRoot implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Information Information;

    private List<Entry> Entries;

}
```

1 - Is possible to send the `<Entry></Entry>` objects tags without wrapping them inside the "entries" list?

2 - Can I configure Spring to return the tags with capitalized name? "Entry" instead of "entry"? Is this even possible? **I managed to do this by adding @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class) annotation in the VehicleRoot class**

I would like to be able to change the system specification, but I'm afraid that I won't be able to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER WITH THE SOLUTION FOR THE CASE:**

Simply create a getter for the desired List with the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` annotation above it:

```
private List<Entry> Entries = new ArrayList<>();

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
public List<Entry> getEntries() {
    return this.Entries;
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Jackson's XmlMapper has [a special feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.Builder.html#defaultUseWrapper-boolean-) to enable or disable wrapping for xml lists.

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper xmlMapper() {
    return XmlMapper.builder()
        ...
        .defaultUseWrapper(false)
        ...
        .build();
}
```

If you use the default (autoconfigured) xmlMapper, you can add `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` with the same setting:

```
@Bean
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer xmlWrapperCustomizer() {
    return mapperBuilder -> mapperBuilder.defaultUseWrapper(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, after adding the second bean I am receiving an "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle" and the application doesn't start. Should I do something else?

Comment: Looks like a separate problem... Can the app be launched without that customizer bean?

Comment: Yes, it can be lauched without the customizer bean. But, I managed to unwrap the list by using the "@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)" annotation above a manually typed getter "public List<Entry> getEntries()" which returns the entries. Please, update your answer adding this tip so I may mark as answer.